# como llamar a un metodo

Tags: java, eclipse

tengo un problema con mi código, el código tiene 3 paquetes, uno llamado mundo, otro interfaz y el ultimo teléfonos, este último me lo creo el propio eclipse ya que hacía falta. El problema es que al momento de querer imprimir el teléfono más vendido, el menos vendido y el costo promedio de venta, no lo hace, se supone que llamé de forma correcta al método pero aun así no me lo imprime, llevo mucho tiempo intentando arreglarlo pero no consigo encontrar el error.

**¿Que debe de hacer el código?**

Tengo esas 5 marcas de teléfono, cada marca se identifica con un número, como se puede ver en la siguiente "lista".

el numero 1 es el iPhone 14

el numero 2 es el Samsung Galaxy

el numero 3 es el Motorola G5

el numero 4 es el Huawei P40 Lite

el numero 5 es el Xiaomi 11

Una vez ingresados los datos, el programa debe permitir calcular:
(los datos son, el tipo de marca, si la marca es iPhone 14 se pone el 1, y así respectivamente hasta que el usuario digite los 5 teléfonos que quiere comprar, no es necesario que sea uno de cada marca, se pueden repetir.)

• Sumatoria (total a pagar sin descuentos)
• Promedio (costo promedio de venta de los teléfonos)
• Cuántos teléfonos son de cada marca
• Teléfono más vendido
• Teléfono menos vendido

**¿Qué error tengo?**

Al intentar imprimir el teléfono más vendido, el menos vendido y el promedio, el código no lo hace, eclipse no me marca ningún error, simplemente no me los imprime, eso es lo que no consigo resolver
A continuación dejo el código:

MUNDO:

```
package mundo;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import Telefono.Telefono;

public class Mundo {
    private List<Telefono> telefonos;
    
    public Mundo() {
        telefonos = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    
    public void agregarTelefono(Telefono telefono) {
        telefonos.add(telefono);
    }
    
    public double calcularTotal() {
        double total = 0;
        for (Telefono telefono : telefonos) {
            total += telefono.getValorVenta();
        }
        return total;
    }
    
    public double calcularDescuento() {
        double descuento = 0;
        int cantMarca1 = 0, cantMarca2 = 0, cantMarca5 = 0;
        for (Telefono telefono : telefonos) {
            if (telefono.getMarca() == 1) {
                cantMarca1++;
            } else if (telefono.getMarca() == 2) {
                cantMarca2++;
            } else if (telefono.getMarca() == 5) {
                cantMarca5++;
            }
        }
        if (cantMarca1 >= 3) {
            descuento += 0.02;
        }
        if (cantMarca2 >= 2) {
            descuento += 0.03;
        }
        if (cantMarca5 >= 3) {
            descuento += 0.04;
        }
        return descuento;
    }
    
    public double calcularSubtotal() {
        double total = calcularTotal();
        double descuento = calcularDescuento();
        return total - (total * descuento);
    }
    
    public double calcularIVA() {
        return calcularSubtotal() * 0.19;
    }
    
    public double calcularValorNeto() {
        return calcularSubtotal() + calcularIVA();
    }
    
    public Telefono getTelefonoMasVendido() {
        Telefono telefonoMasVendido = null;
        int cantidadMasVendida = 0;
        for (Telefono telefono : telefonos) {
            int cantidad = 0;
            for (Telefono otroTelefono : telefonos) {
                if (telefono.equals(otroTelefono)) {
                    cantidad++;
                }
            }
            if (cantidad > cantidadMasVendida) {
                cantidadMasVendida = cantidad;
                telefonoMasVendido = telefono;
            }
        }
        return telefonoMasVendido;
    }

    public Telefono getTelefonoMenosVendido() {
        Telefono telefonoMenosVendido = null;
        int cantidadMenosVendida = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        for (Telefono telefono : telefonos) {
            int cantidad = 0;
            for (Telefono otroTelefono : telefonos) {
                if (telefono.equals(otroTelefono)) {
                    cantidad++;
                }
            }
            if (cantidad < cantidadMenosVendida) {
                cantidadMenosVendida = cantidad;
                telefonoMenosVendido = telefono;
            }
        }
        return telefonoMenosVendido;
    }

    public double calcularPromedio() {
        double totalCosto = 0;
        int cantidad = 0;
        for (Telefono telefono : telefonos) {
            totalCosto += telefono.getCostoProduccion();
            cantidad++;
        }
        return totalCosto / cantidad;
    }
}
```

INTERFAZ:

```
package interfaz;

import java.util.Scanner;

import Telefono.Telefono;
import mundo.Mundo;

public class Interfaz {
    private Scanner scanner;
    private Mundo mundo;
    
    public Interfaz() {
        scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        mundo = new Mundo();
    }
    public void leerDatos() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            System.out.print("Ingrese el tipo de teléfono " + (i+1) + ": ");
            int tipo = scanner.nextInt();
            System.out.print("Ingrese el valor de venta del teléfono " + (i+1) + ": ");
            double valorVenta = scanner.nextDouble();
            
            Telefono telefono = new Telefono(tipo,valorVenta);
            mundo.agregarTelefono(telefono);
        }
    }
    public void mostrarResultados() {
        System.out.println("Total: $" + mundo.calcularTotal());
        System.out.println("Descuento: $" + mundo.calcularTotal() * mundo.calcularDescuento());
        System.out.println("Subtotal: $" + mundo.calcularSubtotal());
        System.out.println("Valor IVA: $" + mundo.calcularIVA());
        System.out.println("Valor neto a pagar: $" + mundo.calcularValorNeto());
        System.out.println("El telefono mas vendido es: " + mundo.getTelefonoMasVendido());
        System.out.println("El telefono menos vendido es: " + mundo.getTelefonoMenosVendido());
        System.out.println("Costo promedio de venta de los teléfonos: $" + mundo.calcularPromedio());
    }
}
```

TELEFONO:

```
package Telefono;

public class Telefono {

    public Telefono(int tipo, double valorVenta) {
    }

    public double getValorVenta() {
        return 0;
    }

    public int getMarca() {
        return 0;
    }

    public double getCostoProduccion() {
        return 0;
    }

    public String getTipo() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Qué hace el código actualmente? ¿Imprime algo? ¿Qué imprime? ¿Da error? ¿Qué error? Pulsa en [edit] y completa la pregunta.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que hice para solucionar el error de que me imprimiera 0 fue el modificar la clase Telefono, agregandole lo siguiente:

```
package Telefono;

public class Telefono {
    private int tipo;
    private double valorVenta;
    private int marca;
    private double costoProduccion;
    
    public Telefono(int tipo, double valorVenta, int marca, double costoProduccion) {
        this.tipo = tipo;
        this.valorVenta = valorVenta;
        this.marca = marca;
        this.costoProduccion = costoProduccion;
    }
    
    public int getTipo() {
        return tipo;
    }
    
    public double getValorVenta() {
        return valorVenta;
    }
    
    public int getMarca() {
        return marca;
    }
    
    public double getCostoProduccion() {
        return costoProduccion;
    }
    
    public void setTipo(int tipo) {
        this.tipo = tipo;
    }
    
    public void setValorVenta(double valorVenta) {
        this.valorVenta = valorVenta;
    }
    
    public void setMarca(int marca) {
        this.marca = marca;
    }
    
    public void setCostoProduccion(double costoProduccion) {
        this.costoProduccion = costoProduccion;
    }
   
}
```

Aún no he logrado que me imprima los teléfonos más vendidos y menos vendidos.

Comment: Por si a caso, esto no es un foro. Si tienes otra pregunta, haz una nueva. Si quieres agregar algo, edítala. Y si algo soluciona el problema publicalo como respuesta.

Comment: Muy buena tu solución, para obtener los más y menos vendidos, puedes usar las variables tipo **cantMarca1** y similares, ya que contienen las cantidades vendidas de cada marca, solo resta compararlas entre si ( y agregar marca3 y marca4).

Answer (score 0):

Cambios en **Interfaz**.

```
public void leerDatos() {
   System.out.print( "Telefonos disponiles:\n 1: iPhone\n 2: Samsung Galaxy\n 3: Motorola G5\n 4: Huawei P40 Lite\n 5: Xiaomi 11\n" );
   for( int i = 0; i < 5; i++ ) {
      System.out.print( "Ingrese el tipo de teléfono " + ( i + 1 ) + ": " );
      int tipo = scanner.nextInt();
      Telefono telefono = new Telefono( tipo );
      mundo.agregarTelefono( telefono );
   }
   mostrarResultados();
}

public static void main( String[] args ) {
    Interfaz in = new Interfaz();
    in.leerDatos();
}
```

Tu código está casi perfecto, solo se te olvido llamar a **mostrarResultados**, y como no se desde donde instancias **Interfaz** le agregué un "main".

Agrego la clase **Telefono** con los métodos implementados.

```
public class Telefono {     
   double valorVenta;
   double costoProduccion;
   String nombre;
   int marca;

   public Telefono( int tipo ) {
      marca = tipo;
      if( tipo == 1 ) {
         valorVenta = 100;
         costoProduccion = 90;
         nombre = "iPhone";
      }
      else if( tipo == 2 ) {
         valorVenta = 90;
         costoProduccion = 80;
         nombre = "Samsung Galaxy";
      }
      else if( tipo == 3 ) {
         valorVenta = 85;
         costoProduccion = 75;
         nombre = "Motorola G5";
      }
      else if( tipo == 4 ) {
         valorVenta = 80;
         costoProduccion = 60;
         nombre = "Huawei P40 Lite";
      }
      else if( tipo == 5 ) {
         valorVenta = 70;
         costoProduccion = 60;
         nombre = "Xiaomi 11";
      }      
   }
   
   public double getCostoProduccion() {
      return costoProduccion; 
   }

   public double getValorVenta( ) {
      return valorVenta;
   }

   public String getNombre() {
      return nombre;
   }

   public int getMarca() {
      return marca;
   }
}
```

Comment: al agregar el "main" ahora el código no me está generando los resultados de antes, por ejemplo, antes cuando digitaba todos los precios y marcas me daba el total (si ingresaba que todo valía 100, me daba como total 500, pero, ahora me da como total 0, y así me pasa con todo lo demás, cuando quito ese "main" y devuelvo mi código como lo tenía antes de agregar lo que me dijiste, me pide que agregue un "main" cosa que no me pedía antes. (perdón si parece una "pregunta" tonta, pero hasta hace unos 3 días volví a retomar java desde 0 y no me acuerdo de mucho)

Comment: Hola Jose, disculpa, la verdad es que miré por encima tu código y encontré esa falta, y publiqué la respuesta, no miré que tu clase **Telefono** solo tiene el esqueleto, faltan implementar todos los métodos. Con respecto al método **main** lo agregué para probar, no para necesariamente lo uses, toda aplicación de java, debe tener al menos un método **main**, ya que es lo primero que se ejecuta.

Comment: Hay otra clase en tu aplicación?.

Comment: Las respuestas no deberían de necesitar pedir clarificación a quien pregunta, te recomiendo revisar como responder https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: @JoséHidalgo, edite mi respuesta, queda pendiente rehacer los métodos, **getTelefonoMasVendido** y **getTelefonoMenosVendido**, que no funcionan bien (al menos **getTelefonoMasVendido**).

Comment: @MarcePuente Gracias, ya pude arreglar el error que me generaba que me imprimiera todo en 0, como dijiste, la clase teléfono era solo un esqueleto, por lo tanto la modifiqué y le añadí varias cosas haciendo que esta funcionara.